# delete node linked list recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm learning data structures and try to understand Linked lists in Java. My problem is that i have troubles with deleting nodes at a given index recursively. My goal is to get O(log n) instead of using loops and end up with O(n).

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    int index=0;
    Node temp;
    Node prev;
    public LinkedList(Node head){
        this.head=head;
        temp=head;
        prev=null;
    }
    public int length(){
        int counter=0;
        Node n= head.next;
        while(n!=null){
            counter=counter+1;
            n=n.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public void push(Node newNode){
        newNode.next=head;
        head=newNode;
    }
    public void add(Node prevNode, int value){
        if(prevNode==null){
            System.out.println("The given previous node can not be null!");
            return;
        }
        Node newNode= new Node(value,null);
        newNode.next=prevNode.next;
        prevNode.next=newNode;
    }
    public void add(int index, int value){
        length();
        if((index<0)||(index>length())){
            System.out.println("Array out of bound!");
            return;
        }
        if(index==0){
            push(new Node(value,null));
            return;
        }
        Node newNode= new Node(value,null);
        Node prevNode=head;
            for(int i=1;i<index;i++){
            prevNode=prevNode.next;
        }
        newNode.next=prevNode.next;
        prevNode.next=newNode;
    }
    public void delete(){
        head=head.next;
    }
    public void delete(int index){
        if((index<0)||(index>length())){
            System.out.println("Array out of bound!");
            return;
        }
        if(index==0){
            delete();
        return;}
        if(head.next==null||head==null){
            head=null;
        return;}
        if(this.index!=index){
            this.index++;
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp.next;
            delete(index);
        }if(this.index==index){
            prev=temp.next;
        }
    }
    public void search(int value){
        if(head!=null){
        if(value!=head.value){
            head=head.next;
            index=index+1;
            search(value);
        }else if(value==head.value){
            System.out.println("The value \""+value+"\" was found in index: "+index);}}}
    public void display(){
        Node n= head;
        System.out.print("{");
        while(n!=null){
            System.out.print(" ("+n.value+") ");
            n=n.next;
        }System.out.print("}");
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        LinkedList ll= new LinkedList(new Node(2,null));
        ll.push(new Node(5,null));
        ll.push(new Node(6,null));
        ll.push(new Node(13,null));
        ll.push(new Node(1,null));
        ll.display();
        ll.add(ll.head.next,8);
        ll.display();
        ll.add(0, 0);
        ll.display();
        ll.add(6, 4);
        ll.display();
        System.out.println(ll.length());
        ll.search(13);
        ll.delete(2);
        ll.display();
    }
}
```

So when i'm trying to delete the entry at the index 2, it deletes all the digits before that index but not at that index - so it deletes [0] and [1] but not [2].

For example in this code, the array before deleting is filled with: `{0,1,13,8,6,5,4,2}`.
After calling `delete(2)`, it has the following entries: `{13,8,6,5,4,2}`

***All what i want is to delete only the 13***, so that the array would look like this: `{0,1,8,6,5,4,2}`

I would really appreciate any tips to improve my code.

Comment: who says recursive deletion will be o(logn) in linkedlist ? and why do you want to use recursion ? it can be achieved simple iteration, you just made you code hard to understand

Comment: (+, -, *, / , if)  are one steps, loops are n step, calling function will be n step because the function might contain loop. please correct me if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: I have no idea, what are you talking about

Comment: i know it can be achieved with iteration, but as i said i would like to use recursion so i could improve my knowledge

Comment: you have complete buggy code. It very difficult to tell, what causing this particular issue rather you should prefer to debug your code your own. Ofcourse, I can share the psuedocode to achieve this, since you mentioned, you are trying to improve your knowledge.

Comment: thank you very much, i noticed after debugging that this statement if(this.index!=index) is being skipped for some reason which i don't understand why, because this.index should be in the first run 0 and index is as given 2... i would really appreciate the psuedocode and if you could please explain to me how my code is buggy so i can know what's wrong with what i am doing and avoid it.

Comment: Refer psuedocode. You have used lot of variables, which is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A Java recursive delete method in a linked list

Ok, let's go through this with an example. It's simplistic, but once you get the hang of it and understand the `delete` recursion algorithm, you can easily make the sample classes `generic`, take care of encapsulation, optimize the code and then go on to production.

##### Classes in this example

Assume, for the sake of example, that the basic Singly `LinkedList` and `Node` classes are very simplistic. The inner static `Node` class only stores primitive `int` types and it only includes a `next` reference to the following `Node` element in the list. The `LinkedList` only includes a `head` node, which is the beginning of the linked list. This is not a doubly linked list and it does not have a reference to the previous node. Traversals are done sequentially from the given `Node` (typically head node) through the `next` reference, one node after the other. I've added a `toString()` implementation to both, which will come handy later:

```
public class LinkedList {

protected Node head;

public LinkedList(Node head) {
    super();
    this.head = head;
}

static class Node {

    protected int data;
    protected Node next;

    Node(int data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Node ");
        builder.append(data);
        if (null != next)
            builder.append(" -> ");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("LinkedList [");
    Node node = head;
    while (node != null) {
        builder.append(node);
        node = node.next;
    }
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

##### Implementing a recursive delete method

Now, let's add a recursive `delete()` method. Deleting a node in a singly linked list can only be done by un-linking it from the previous node's `next` reference. The only exception to this rule is the `head` node, which we null to delete. Hence, it is obvious that we'll need (in addition to a starting point `current node` reference), a reference to the previous node.

Thus, our recursive `delete()` method signature can be:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key)
```

Although the return type of this method can be omitted altogether (void) it is very useful to support chain-ability, so that API calls can become one-liner, dot separated syntax such as:

```
System.out.println(list.push(0).append(2).deleteAll(1));
```

Hence, for the sake of chain-ability, we'll return a reference to the entire `LinkedList` instance from this method too. As per the arguments list:

The first argument is the current node to check if it matches the given `key`. The next argument is the previous node, in case we need to un-link the current node. The last argument is the key we're looking for in all nodes to be deleted (unlinked).

The method modifier is `private` because it's not meant to be used publicly. We'll wrap it in a user friendly `facade` method, which will start the recursion with `head` as the current node and `null` as the previous node:

```
public LinkedList deleteAll(int key) {
    return delete(head, null, key);
}
```

Now, let's see how we can implement the recursive `delete(...)` method and we begin with the two base conditions that will terminate the recursion; a null current node or a single node in the list, which is also the `head` node:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    if (node == null)
        return this;
    if (node == head && head.data == key && null == head.next) { // head node w/o next pointer
        head = null;
        return this;
    }
    //...more code here
}
```

Reaching the first base condition means either that we've reached the end of the linked list (found the `key` or not), or that the linked list is empty. We're done and we return a reference to the linked list.

The second base condition checks to see if our current node is the head node, and that it matches the `key`. In this case we also check if it happens to be the single node in the linked list. In such case the head node requires a 'special' treatment and must be assigned `null` in order to be deleted. Naturally, after deleting the `head` node, the list is empty and we're done, so we return a reference to the linked list.

The next condition checks if the current node matches the `key`, if it's the head node, but is not alone in the list.

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    //...previous code here
    if (node == head && head.data == key) { // head with next pointer
        head = head.next;
        return delete(head, null, key);
    }
    //...more code here
}
```

We'll later optimize this code but for now, in such a case we simply move the reference to `head` one step forward, so `head` is effectively deleted (the old reference will be garbage collected) and we recur with the new `head` as the current node and `null` is still the previous node.

The next case covers a regular (middle or tail) node matching the `key`:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    //...previous code here
    if (node.data == key) {
        prev.next = node.next;
        return delete(prev, null, key);
    }
    //...more code here
}
```

In this case we delete the current node by un-linking the `next` pointer of the previous node from the current node and assigning it the next to the current node address. We essentially 'skip' the current node, which becomes grabage. We then recur with the previous node being the current node and null as the previous node.

In all of these handled cases we had a match for `key`. Finally, we handle the case where there's no match:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    //...previous code here
    return delete(node.next, node, key);
}
```

Obviously, we recur with the next node as the current node, and the old current node as the previous node. The `key` remains the same through all recursion calls.

The entire (un-optimized) method now looks like this:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    if (node == null)
        return this;
    if (node.data == key && node == head && null == node.next) { // head node w/o next pointer
        head = null;
        return this;
    }
    if (node.data == key && node == head) { // head with next pointer
        head = head.next;
        return delete(head, null, key);
    }
    if (node.data == key) { // middle / tail
        prev.next = node.next;
        return delete(prev, null, key);
    }
    return delete(node.next, node, key);
}
```

##### Tail Recursion Optimization

Many compilers (javac included) can optimize recursive methods, if they use a tail-recursion. A recursive method is tail recursive when a recursive call is the last thing executed by the method. The compiler can then replace the recursion with a simple `goto/label` mechanism and save the  extra memory space required in run-time for each recursion frame.

We can easily optimize our recursive `delete(...)` method to comply. Instead of returning recursively from each of the handled conditions (cases) we can keep a reference to the current `node` and previous node `prev` and assign them with appropriate values inside each case handling. This way, the only recursive call will happen at the end of the method:

```
private LinkedList delete(Node node, Node prev, int key) {
    if (node == null)
        return this;
    if (node.data == key && head == node && null == node.next) { // head node w/o next pointer
        head = null;
        return this;
    }
    Node n = node.next, p = node;
    if (node.data == key && head == node) { // head with next pointer
        head = head.next;
        n = head;
        p = null;
    } else if (node.data == key) { // middle / tail
        prev.next = node.next;
        n = prev;
        p = null;
    }
    return delete(n, p, key);
}
```

##### To test this recursive method:

I've added a simple `main` test driver method to test the `delete(...)` method implementation, via the facade method `deleteAll(...)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(new Node(0, new Node(1, new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(2, new Node(3, null)))))));
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.deleteAll(6));
    System.out.println(list.deleteAll(1));
    System.out.println(list.deleteAll(3));
    System.out.println(list.deleteAll(2));
    System.out.println(list.deleteAll(0));
}
```

The output (using my supplied `toString()` methods) is:

```
LinkedList [Node 0 -> Node 1 -> Node 1 -> Node 2 -> Node 2 -> Node 3]
LinkedList [Node 0 -> Node 1 -> Node 1 -> Node 2 -> Node 2 -> Node 3]
LinkedList [Node 0 -> Node 2 -> Node 2 -> Node 3]
LinkedList [Node 0 -> Node 2 -> Node 2]
LinkedList [Node 0]
LinkedList []
```

Although it's been 3 years since the initial post, I trust some other beginning Java programmers, if not the OP, find this explanation useful.

Answer (score 1):

It was very difficult to understand your code, but as you asked for logic to improve your understanding, so sharing psuedocode, which you could refer to correct your code accordingly.

```
Node delete (index i, Node n) // pass index and head reference node and return head
   if (n==null) // if node is null
      return null;
   if (i==1)  // if reached to node, which needs to be deleted, return next node reference.
      return n.next;  
   n.next= delete(n.next,i-1);
   return n; // recursively return current node reference
```

Answer (score 0):

after struggling i managed to solve the problem, here is the answer, but i am still not sure about the complexity whether it's O(n) or O(log n).

```
 public void delete(int index){
        //check if the index is valid
        if((index<0)||(index>length())){
            System.out.println("Array out of bound!");
            return;
        }
        //pass the value head to temp only in the first run
        if(this.index==0)
            temp=head;
        //if the given index is zero then move the head to next element and return
        if(index==0){
            head=head.next;
        return;}
        //if the array is empty or has only one element then move the head to null
        if(head.next==null||head==null){
            head=null;
        return;}
        if(temp!=null){
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp.next;
            this.index=this.index+1;
            //if the given index is reached
           //then link the node prev to the node that comes after temp
          //and unlink temp
            if(this.index==index){
                prev.next=temp.next;
                temp=null;
                return;
            }
         //if not then call the function again
           delete(index);
        }
    }
```