# Delete a node in a linked list recursively

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The below code deletes a node in a linked list using iteration.
Now I would like to to delete a node using recursion:

```
def delete(self, key):
    temp = self.head
    if (temp is not None):
        if temp.data == key:
            self.head = temp.next
            temp = None
            return
    if temp is None:
        return
    while (temp is not None):
        if temp.data == key:
            break
        prev = temp
        temp = temp.next
    prev.next = temp.next
    temp = None
```

I don't see how I can make this recursive...

Comment: You have at least three answers below. Any feed-back on those?

Comment: I've demonstrated a similar Java solution for a singly list in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485863/1272886

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleteNode(root, key):
    if not root:
        return None
    if root.data == key: # delete the first node of linked list
        return root.next
    if root.next:
        next = deleteNode(root.next, key)
        root.next = next
    return root
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have attempted to correct it. You need to assign prev before break as break will exit from the loop and your prev and temp will never be assigned in some cases.

```
def delete(self,key):
    temp=self.head
    if(temp is not None):
        if temp.data==key:
            self.head=temp.next
            temp=None
            return
    if temp is None:
        return
    while(temp is not None):
        prev=temp
        temp=temp.next
        if temp.data==key:
            break
    prev.next=temp.next
    temp=None
```

Comment: Though I have made a correction here, I believe this is not a perfect method. You are supplying the key to the method so it will delete the first occurrence of the key only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code will run into an exception when the data is not found in the list. Secondly, it is not necessary to do `temp = None` just before exiting the function.

To cope with the first issue, the iterative function could be:

```
def deleteNode(self, key):
    prev = None
    node = self.head
    while node and node.data != key:
        prev = node
        node = node.next
    if node == self.head:
        self.head = node.next
    elif node:
        prev.next = node.next
```

The recursive version:

```
def deleteNode(self, key):
    def recur(node):
        if node:
            if node.data == key:
                return node.next
            node.next = recur(node.next)
        return node

    self.head = recur(self.head)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering singly linked list of integers and position(pos) 'i'.
Deleting the node present at the 'i-th' position

```
def deleteNodeRec(head, pos) :
    #Your code goes here
    if pos == 0:
        return head.next
    if (head.next is None):
        return head
    head.next = deleteNodeRec(head.next,pos-1)
    return head
```

Reference: https://www.svastikkka.com/2022/07/delete-node-recursive.html